# using JFace text Singlelinerule

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp

Is it possible to use the `Singlelinerule` in `RuleBasedPartitionScanner` to detect 
whether the partition starts with an alphabet or space ?

Comment: SingleLineRule only accept specific strings as the start and end sequence so you can only use it to create a partition that starts and ends with that sequence (same with MultiLineRule). Try and explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use syntax highlighting for JCL language. I am partitioning the doucument using the following rules: 1. Lines that start with '//' 2. Lines that start with '//*' 3. Lines that starts with '/*' 4. any other line.   my question is how to accomplish #4 in my list above using a `SinlelineRule`

Answer (score 1):

If you have rules for //, //* and /* you don't need a rule to cover the remaining text - that text will be put in the default `IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` partition.

Update:

Neither `SingleLineRule` or its parent class `PatternRule` support testing for a range of characters. However you could write your own implementation of `IPredicateRule` to do this, look at the `PatternRule` implementation to see how columns and match is handled.

Comment: Yes I thought of using the `IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` but since I was anticipating further partitioning in future, I thought of defining  a specific rule which is "Line starting with any other String other than //, //* or /* ". Also not sure if `WordRule` will be helpful. Will have to tryout to see if it works

Comment: Added a bit on what you could do to match the other lines